# URLLIB Request unable to handle Chinese Character

Tags: python, parsing, python-3.x, google-api, urllib

I'm trying to do a curl request to api but the chinese chracter is giving a error

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 96-97: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Unlike in php where i can simply just throw the character into curl but python seem to be different. Any idea how i can do the same?

Here's the code I'm using:

```
 query = urllib.parse.urlencode({'': '不存'})
        url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2' + query
        print(url);
        search_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        search_results = search_response.read().decode("utf8")
        results = json.loads(search_results)
        data = results['responseData']
        print(data);
```

Comment: What line is the exception occuring at? I suspect it's the first `print` and not the `urllib` logic that's having trouble -- you should be printing unicode strings to the console, not byte strings (`url` is a byte string since it's encoded in UTF-8, I believe).

Comment: @Cameron You are right, why cant i print chinese character :( anyway to "print" it without getting an error

Comment: You need to be both using a terminal that is Unicode aware (if you're using the Windows command prompt you're pretty much out of luck), and also writing Unicode strings instead of encoded byte strings (e.g. `print(url.decode("utf8"))` instead). If all else fails, just write it (encoded) to a log file.